# Added paging support to JNDI LDAP connection results in AuthenticationException

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

we develop some Java software and amongst others we have an LDAP connection there:

```
final DirContext dirContext = new InitialDirContext(new Hashtable<>(env));
```

Since some customers enabled paging in their Active Directory we have to support that in our code and changed it therefore as it is described everywhere:

```
final InitialLdapContext ctx =  new InitialLdapContext(new Hashtable<>(env), null);
ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, Control.NONCRITICAL) });
...
```

Pretty straight forward so far, but:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090421, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0^@]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3136)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3082)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
```

This happens right at the beginning, when creating the new context. The only difference to the usage of InitialDirContext I could find is, that the InitialLdapContext adds one key to the environment hash:

```
java.naming.ldap.version=3
```

I have no idea where to look and for what. Maybe the Active Directory only supports LDAP v2 (could this be possible)? Is something missing in our code? Is this some configuration issue the LDAP administrator can only solve? Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards,
Manuel

Comment: Versions of LDAP should be displayed within the rootDSE and AD does support LDAPv3. As I recall, LDAPv2 did not have controls or extensions.

Comment: @jwilleke That's right, v2 does not support controls. However, the target AD works with v3 (I got this information from the administrator some minutes ago), so I have no idea what's wrong with our implementation :(

Comment: [LDAP: error code 49 .. data 52e is a clear indication that the password is invalid for the provided user.

Comment: @jwilleke I know, but as I wrote I get no exception when I use
`new InitialDirContext(new Hashtable<>(env));` where `env` is exactly the same as in `new InitialLdapContext(new Hashtable<>(env), null);`